# Kncokout validator with mix events: first time with value binding and seconds time with textInput binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-3.0

I need a "Input" validate the first time to lose focus(like a value binding), but the following times is validated with afterkeydown(like a textInput binding ).

The behavior would be similar to the email field on this page:
https://www.gosquared.com/join/

Answer (score 0):

Add **valueUpdate: 'input'** to your binding. It will trigger the validation on change of the input rather than on focus/blur.

Example:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'input'"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolov, that is the behavior of text Input (knockout 3.x); but only to behave so after the first time the focus was lost.

I was thinking of a custom bind, and the attack init event focus, remove the bind of value and put the the textInput; but not if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Like a this validator: http://imgur.com/OEeSqDo

First time vaidate on focus, last times validate on keypress.